# Local APT Repository

Tags: apt, 22.04, repository

I started a local apt repository, but I want the client settings to be in such a way that if the local repo server was unavailable, the client will download the packages from the default ubuntu repos.
Somehow the priority of local repo should be more.
Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Simply adding your local repository sources links at the top and following them by the links for the remote ones in `/etc/apt/sources.lis` should do what you want (given that the packages versions provided by both are the same) … I think but haven’t tested it.

Comment: @Raffa Don't you mean /etc/apt/sources.list ?

Comment: @ElderGeek Thank you … that’s the file I mean indeed … I mistyped and skipped the last "t" … I'm not friends with my phone's small keyboard as it seems :)